# Is there any way to check whether a PostgreSQL record- or row-type variable contains a specific field from inside a function?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, record

I have a trigger defined on several tables to fire after all `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`, all using the same trigger function. The trigger function performs an expensive check, but I can speed it up significantly by filtering some of the intermediate steps of that check using either a `WHERE machine_serial = NEW.machine_serial` or `WHERE machine_serial = OLD.machine_serial` clause, depending on what type of statement fired the trigger. However, not all the tables actually have a `machine_serial` column, so I can't perform this filtering when the trigger is fired on one of those tables. I am currently trying to find a good solution to making the decision of whether to filter or not from within the trigger function, and I believe that simply checking whether `NEW` or `OLD` has the `machine_serial` field would be easiest, clearest, and fastest. I can't find any way to do that in the documentation though, but checking whether a `RECORD` contains a certain field seems like such a basic, commonplace operation for anyone that has to work with `RECORD`s that I assume that I've just got to be missing it somewhere - I can't imagine that it's just not possible.

For completeness, I'll go over the alternatives I've considered to the hypothetical does-`RECORD`-have-field check:

- I could create two trigger functions, `do_expensive_check_with_machine_serial()` and `do_expensive_check_without_machine_serial()`, and use one or the other depending on whether the table has the `machine_serial` column. But if I or anyone after me needs to alter the logic in either one of these functions, they'll need to remember to alter the logic in the other one, too.
- I could stick with the one trigger function I currently have, and figure out whether the firing table has `machine_serial` by just trying to access `NEW.machine_serial` or `OLD.machine_serial`. If that raises an exception, I can catch it and then I'll know the field isn't present. But the manual [explicitly suggests avoiding using exception blocks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/plpgsql-control-structures.html#TRAPPING-ERRORS) unless absolutely necessary, due to performance impacts.
- I could stick with the one trigger function I currently have, and just add a check like this: `IF (TG_TABLE_SCHEMA = x AND TG_TABLE_NAME = y) OR (TG_TABLE_SCHEMA = w AND TG_TABLE_NAME = z) OR ...`
  , and just maintain that list of every table that has a `machine_serial` column. But then I and anyone that comes after me would need to alter that check in the trigger function any time the trigger is added to a new table, which is less than ideal.

Of course, the above three alternatives would all *function*, but they all feel like bad design choices to me. Maybe it's because I'm used to the dynamicness offered by Python, but if I used any of these alternatives, I would feel like I'm doing something wrong. And PostgreSQL is pretty good about offering lots of operators on all sorts of data types, so I just can't imagine that something as basic as checking whether a `RECORD` or `ROW`-type variable contains a certain field is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Before I show the solution, I have to say, so this requirement can be signal of some unhappy design. Maybe you try to implement some functionality that should not be implemented in triggers. Triggers are good, but too smart too generic too rich can be very slow and very hard to maintain and fix errors (but as every in life, there are exceptions from rules).

So first - you can look to system catalog:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.foo_trg() RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 AS $$
begin
  raise notice 'a exists %', exists(select * from pg_attribute where attrelid = new.tableoid and attname = 'a');
  raise notice 'd exists %', exists(select * from pg_attribute where attrelid = new.tableoid and attname = 'd');    
  return new;
end;
$$; 

CREATE TABLE public.foo (
   a integer,
   b integer
);

CREATE TRIGGER foo_trg_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON public.foo
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION public.foo_trg();

(2022-09-02 06:18:41) postgres=# insert into foo values(1,2);
NOTICE:  a exists t
NOTICE:  d exists f
INSERT 0 1
```

Second solution is based on record to jsonb transformations:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo_trg()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
  declare j jsonb;
begin
  j := to_jsonb(new);
  raise notice 'a exists %', j ? 'a';    
  raise notice 'd exists %', j ? 'd';    
  return new;
end;
$$

(2022-09-02 06:24:54) postgres=# insert into foo values(1,2);
NOTICE:  a exists t
NOTICE:  d exists f
INSERT 0 1
```

Second solution can be faster, because doesn't requires queries to system catalog. It hits just system catalog cache, but it doesn't work on some legacy PostgreSQL releases.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This will be very helpful. Also, I appreciate the concern. The trigger needs to perform such heavy work because it needs to inspect the results of a query that combines data from several tables together - the tables essentially define the default data collection rules for different types of machines, the exceptions to those rules for specific machines (e.g. water treatment machine type X serial number #1330), and the exceptions to those rules for specific sites, with site rules overriding base rules on conflict, and machine rules overriding base and site rules on conflict.

Comment: That design choice makes it very easy to specify the data collection rules, since exceptions to the base rules are generally rare. We can easily say things like "type-X machines with software version 4.30 and above collect A B C fields from x y z addresses", and then as soon as any type-X machine's software is updated to 4.30, we will collect data from it according to the proper rules with no intervention required. Whereas if we stored the rules in an exploded format, we'd need to update the rules manually whenever a machine's software is updated to a version that changes the rules.

Comment: Or say we need to record some data D from any machine installed at site S, we just specify "collect data D from address x" in the site override table. Then, even if we install some machine at site S, remove it, replace it with another one, whatever, we don't need to do anything to keep the data collection rules accurate. Whereas if we stored the rules in an exploded format, we'd need to manually update the rules as soon as a machine is installed or replaced at a site that requires extra data, and we may only find out the exact time a machine was moved a day or two later.

Comment: So splitting the rules into base sets and overrides makes specifying rules easy, but makes validating them harder. Now you may be asking, "why are you polling data from machines instead of having them push it to you, so that you don't need to specify ANY of this in the database? This should be handled in the software of the machines themselves." And I agree, but unfortunately I have no sway over how the hardware is designed. I am in charge of the backend though, and this was the best solution I could come up with given our needs. 
Sorry for the wall of text, I just felt the need to explain

Comment: @NickMuise - no problem, I know so sometimes the easy and good solutions are not possible due some reasons that we cannot to change.